# payable() function In solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I dont really understand payable() should i use

```
contract(){
receive() {
 somefunction()
}

somefunction() payable external{
}
```

or it is enough to use

```
contract(){

somefunction() payable external{}
}
```

do they need to be used together -  we use fallback function and some normal payable modifier what is the difference of using them both or just fallback or just somefunction? What if there are 2 functions with modifier payable can you give me some examples?

Answer (score 15):

The presence of the **payable** modifier means that the function can process transactions with non-zero Ether value. If a transaction that transfers Ether comes to the contract and calls some function X, then if this function X does not have the **payable** modifier, then the transaction will be rejected.
The **fallback** function is designed to handle the situation when no function is called at all in a transaction comes to the contract (for example, the transaction simply transfers ether), or a function is called that is not in the contract. In this case, similar to the one described above - if the **fallback** function has the **payable** modifier, then it will be able to accept transactions with the transfer of Ether, if not, then they will be rejected.

Accordingly, in your case, if Ether is being transmitted in the transaction, the function **somefunction** will be called successfully, and when the **receive** function is called, the transaction will be rejected.

```
contract(){
receive() {
 somefunction()
}

somefunction() payable external{
}
```

Comment: Note that payable modifier strictly deals with ETH payment and tokens like ERC-20 have different mechanisms when interacting with smart contracts.

Comment: Thank You now i understand Can we have 2 or more payable functions?And if someone will send ether to contract without using some function  the default receive function will be called?

Comment: 1.Yes and 2. Yes.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa do you have a link about this?

Comment: It's a different question.